# Cordova play local videos without loading it all?

Tags: cordova

I'm using `cordova-plugin-file` to access videos saved in the `Download` folder, then set it as source of a video element, which works fine.

My issue is that, no matter which preload attribute I use, it appears that the video is fully loaded before it can play, which takes a few minutes as the videos can be large (800+ MB).

Stripped code:

```
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Download/myvideo.mp4', 
 function(__res){
        video.oncanplay = function(){video.play()};
        video.src = __res.toInternalURL();           
 }, fail);
```

HTML

```
 <div class="video">
    <video loop playsinline controls width="100%" height="100%" preload="metadata"></video>
</div>
```

Is there a better approach ? Can I stream the file instead ?